# I'm using jplayer to play shoutcast streams, I encountered strange issue where 1 stream works and other doesn't

Tags: jplayer, shoutcast

I've weirdest problem where I can successfully play 1 shoutcast station and cannot some other using jplayer. This is strange as information of shoutcast server hints on similar configuration:

```
http://198.27.79.224:9770/

http://108.61.73.119:8128/
```

I must also note that flash version of jplayer plays both, but html version only plays first one.

Jplayer js looks like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function(){
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
      jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
      cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
      {
        title:"#1 Stream",
        mp3:"http://108.61.73.119:8128/;stream/1"
      },
      {
        title:"#2 Stream",
        mp3:"http://108.61.73.118:8128/;stream/1"
      },
      {
        title:"#3 Stream",
        mp3:"http://108.61.73.117:8128/;stream/1"
      },
      {
        title:"#4 Stream",
        mp3:"http://198.27.79.224:9770/;stream/1"
      },
    ], {
       swfPath: "jplayer",
       supplied: "mp3",
       wmode: "window",
       preload: "none",
       //solution: "flash, html",
      smoothPlayBar: true,
      keyEnabled: true
    });
    $("#jplayer_inspector_1").jPlayerInspector({jPlayer:$("#jquery_jplayer_1")});
  });
  //]]>
  </script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems flash version plays all of the streams, but html5 version only selected few. I never got to the bottom of the problem.